# i got an critical error when i deploy my contract in hardhat

Tags: hardhat, error

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\E:\codings\elonNft\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\edr-win32-x64-msvc\edr.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1338:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\codings\elonNft\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\edr\index.js:72:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Comment: It seems an error within a node dependency. If you are running on windows try using a linux vm.

Answer (score 0):

the device you're using must be missing the widows c++ redistributable. downloading that was how i solved this issue too. https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/3612 this should help you